# Scrape data from website with frames or flexbox using python requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, flexbox

I've been trying to figure this out but with no luck. I found a thread ([How to scrape data from flexbox element/container with Python and Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165635/how-to-scrape-data-from-flexbox-element-container-with-python-and-beautiful-soup)) that I thought would help but I can't seem to make any headway.

The site I'm trying to scrape is...http://www.northwest.williams.com/NWP_Portal/. In particular I want to get the data from the tab/frame of 'Storage Levels' but for the life of me I can't seem to navigate to the right spot to get the data. I've tried various iterations of the code below with no success. I've changed 'lxml' to 'html.parser', looked for tables, looked for 'tr' etc but the code always returns empty.  I've also tried looking at the network info but when I click on any of the tabs (System Status, PAL/System Balancing etc) I don't see any change in network activity. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking but I just can't put my finger on it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

url = 'http://www.northwest.williams.com/NWP_Portal/'

r = requests.get(url)

html = soup(r.content,'lxml')

page = html.findAll('div',{'class':'dailyOperations-panels'})
```

How can I 'navigate' to the 'Storage Levels' frame/tab? What is the html that I'm actually looking for? Can I do this with just requests and beautiful soup? I'm not opposed to using Selenium but I haven't used it before and would prefer to just use requests and BeautifulSoup if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can anyone else offer any insight? it seems like when I request the main URL all I get back is the headers on top, the menu on the left and weather on the right. I can't seem to figure out how to get into the middle where the data. Checking the network activity the only activity I get is when I click on Daily Operations link at the top. Every click inside the main frame doesn't trigger any activity. Sorry if I'm not explaining this correctly. I just need help getting to the data, after that I should be able to retrieve the data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so what I notice is your are trying to get "dailyOperations-panels" from a div which won't work.

Comment: I guess that's where I'm struggling. I've tried a bunch of different findAll's but can't seem to get the right combination. I tried 
```
page = html.findAll('table',{'class':'dailyOperations-panels'})
```
but that doesn't get me anywhere either. The other thread I noted suggested the OP was overthinking things but I'm starting to wonder if I'm trying to be too simplistic and it's not as straightforward as I thought.